# How to enable button if any checkbox of same id checked using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple set of checkboxes each set has 5 check boxes. Each set of checkboxes have same ID.

And every set has a submit button which are disabled.

I am searching for a JavaScript or jQuery code which will enable the button of that set if any checkbox is checked of a particular set.

Please if any body can help me.

for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_abc" value="Submit" disabled>

<input type="checkbox" id="efg" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="efg" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="efg" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="efg" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="efg" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_efg" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: Ids can't be repeated

Comment: ID should be unique in context use class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  var getClass = $(this).attr('class');
  var flag = 0;
  $('input[class="' + getClass + '"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      flag = 1;
  });
  
  if(flag) {
    $('input[name="sub_' + getClass + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[name="sub_' + getClass + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_abc" value="Submit" disabled>

<input type="checkbox" class="efg" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="efg" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="efg" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="efg" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="efg" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_efg" value="Submit" disabled>
```

You can't have same `id`, so I've used `class` instead of `id`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @KaustavDey Welcome buddy :)

Comment: please select the solution that helped you as the correct answer so that others looking for the same solution also get the benefit.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Why such kind of comment? What you wanted to proof?

Comment: read the comment again you will have the answer to your question. It was actually for @KaustavDey . No one wants to prove anything, in fact cant figure out why YOU commented like that.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I comment because I got a notification & more over you haven't tagged any one. If you want to say anything to the OP then say it in the question, not in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use duplicate `id` values. It is invalid in HTML. But you don't need them. Instead group your items with some wrapper element, e.g. a `span`. Then you can use the following jQuery click handler:

```js
$('[name=name\\[\\]]').change(function () {
    $span = $(this).parent();
    $('[type=submit]', $span).prop('disabled', $('[type=checkbox]:checked', $span).length == 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="5">

    <input type="submit" name="sub_abc" value="Submit" disabled>
</span>

<span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="5">

    <input type="submit" name="sub_abc" value="Submit" disabled>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `data-attr` to select group
2. use that `data-attr` to name the button and disable accordingly

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {

  var thisclass = $(this).attr('data-class');
  $('.' + thisclass).prop('disabled', !$(':checkbox[data-class='+thisclass+']').is(':checked'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-class="abc" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="abc" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="abc" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="abc" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="abc" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_abc" class="abc" value="Submit" disabled>

<input type="checkbox" data-class="efg" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="efg" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="efg" name="name[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="efg" name="name[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" data-class="efg" name="name[]" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_abc" class="efg" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the attribute class="abc" to every checkbox
2. Add the attribute id="sub_abc" to submit button

> ```
> $('.abc').change(function(ev) {   
>     var flag = 0;
>     if($('.abc').is(':checked'))
>             flag = 1;
>
>     if(flag) {
>        $('#sub_abc').removeAttr('disabled');
>     } else {
>       $('#sub_abc').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
>     }
> });
> ```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" class="abc" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" class="abc" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" class="abc" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" class="abc" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" name="name[]" class="abc" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="sub_abc" id="sub_abc" value="Submit" disabled>
```